# How to code my own version of mv (rename/move) unix command in C language?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I want to write my own code for move(mv) Unix command. I am completely new to C language and apparently lost on how to fix my code. I want to perform actions like renaming a file if both the inputs are file names. If the the dest_folder is a directory I would like to move the file into the directory.

But I am unable to fix code for the particular problem as I am not much familiar with directories and C in particular. The program takes 2 inputs source and destination after which it performs necessary functions. I am apparently able to rename my files but I am unable to move the file to a particular folder for some reason I don't know?

Need help with moving file to a particular directory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SBUF 256
#define DBUF 256

    int main(int ac, char *argv[])
    {
      DIR* dir_ptr;     // the directory
      struct dirent* direntp;


      if( ac == 1 )
      {
        printf("Usage:  %s MOVE\n", argv[0] );
        exit(0);
      }


      if(ac>1 && ac<3)
      {
        printf("Error! few arguments provided " );
        exit(0);
      }

        char src_folder[SBUF];
        char dest_folder[DBUF];
        strcpy(src_folder, argv[1]);
        strcpy(dest_folder, argv[2]);


        dir_ptr = opendir("."); //open directory
        if ( dir_ptr == NULL )
        {
            perror( "." );
            exit( 1 );
        }

        while( (direntp = readdir( dir_ptr )) != NULL ) 
        {
            if (  strcmp(direntp->d_name, dest_folder) !=0) //search file or directory
            {
                printf("found the file %s", dest_folder);

                break;
            }else
                printf("not found");
                break;
        }
        rename(src_folder, dest_folder);
        closedir( dir_ptr );

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a need for the `opendir`/`readdir`/`closedir`. The [`rename`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) will check for file existence for you.

Comment: You might want to check permission in case they play a role in your tests. Do you see error messages? Can you pinpoint what exactly does not work in your code?

Comment: @Elyasin I am not getting any error message when I run the code on my terminal. Also I am not sure what to pinpoint as there is no error but maybe a part of code that is missing and not allowing me to move or rename file this is whatI cannot figure out?

Comment: @Elyasin apparently I figured out on how to rename which is working correct in my code but I am still unable to move files to a particular folder I don't know why? I changed the permissions also!

Comment: When moving/renaming a file, you just need four things: name of the file, new name for the file, directory of the file, new directory for the file. I believe with these four, you can easily "move" your file. Then permissions are secondary

Comment: Can you post the file permissions. And say what change you lately made to rename a file?

Comment: @khredos I am moving a file from the parent directory to a child directory within the parent directory but when I mention the file name as source input and the Directory input as the destination which is  a child directory it does not move the file to directory for some reason don't know? eg './move myfile.c check' .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rename(3)` does not work the way you want it to work (I don't know why, ask the committee). You cannot do a `rename(some_file, some_directory)`, just as the man-page says.

Just use `stat(2)`  (or `lstat(2)` if necessary) and check what you have been given. Here is a short, runnable sketch.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

    // check if it is the same inode on the same device
#define SAME_INODE(a, b) ((a).st_ino == (b).st_ino && (a).st_dev == (b).st_dev)

    // ALL CHECKS OMMITTED!

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  struct stat statbuf_src, statbuf_dest;
  char *src, *dest, *new_src, *new_dest;
  char *current_directory;

  if (argc != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s src dest\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // work on copy
  src = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 1);
  dest = malloc(strlen(argv[2]) + 1);
  strcpy(src, argv[1]);
  strcpy(dest, argv[2]);

  stat(src, &statbuf_src);
  stat(dest, &statbuf_dest);

  // there are many more, of course
  printf("\"%s\" is a ", src);
  if (S_ISREG(statbuf_src.st_mode)) {
    puts("a regular file");
  }
  if (S_ISDIR(statbuf_src.st_mode)) {
    puts("a directory");
  }

  printf("\"%s\" is a ", dest);
  if (S_ISREG(statbuf_dest.st_mode)) {
    puts("a regular file");
  }
  if (S_ISDIR(statbuf_dest.st_mode)) {
    puts("a directory");
  }

  if (SAME_INODE(statbuf_dest, statbuf_src)) {
    printf("%s and %s are the identical\n", src, dest);
  }
  // if that is not set you have to do it by hand:
  // climb up the tree, concatenating names until the inodes are the same
  current_directory = getenv("PWD");
  printf("current directory is \"%s\"\n", current_directory);

  // I'm pretty sure it can be done in a much more elegant way
  new_src = malloc(strlen(src) + 1 + strlen(current_directory) + 1);
  strcpy(new_src,current_directory);
  strcat(new_src,"/");
  strcat(new_src,src);
  printf("new_src = %s\n",new_src);

  new_dest = malloc(strlen(dest) + 1 + strlen(current_directory) + 1 + strlen(src) + 1);
  strcpy(new_dest,current_directory);
  strcat(new_dest,"/");
  strcat(new_dest,dest);
  strcat(new_dest,"/");
  strcat(new_dest,src);
  printf("new_dest = %s\n",new_dest);

  if(rename(new_src,new_dest) != 0){
    fprintf(stderr,"rename failed with error %s\n",strerror(errno));
  }

  free(new_src);
  free(new_dest);
  free(src);
  free(dest);

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**Edit**: added code for the desciption below
At the end you have a the path where you are, the information if the arguments given are directories or regular files and the path. If the source is a regular file and the destination a directory, you concatenate the path with the name of the regular file, the path with the name of the directory and the name of the regular file (your source)

Out of

```
Path = /home/foo
src = bar
dest = coffee
```

build

```
new_src = /home/foo/bar
new_dest = /home/foo/coffee/bar
```

Such that the call to `rename()` is

```
rename(new_src, new_dest);
```

That way you rename a regular file to a regular file which `rename()` accepts.

Please be aware that `rename()` does not work across *every* filesystem, but most.

Comment: I followed the process that you told me. I did concatenate the path with the regular src file as to move the scr file to directory likewise I did arguments like `./move hello1.txt check` but it did not moved the file to the directory. I do not know why as I did `rename(src_folder, dest_folder);` after the concatenation. What could I have done wrong please mention thanks.

Comment: `src = malloc(strlen(argv[1])); ... strcpy(src,argv[1]);` is certainly insufficient memory allocation.

Comment: @chux Oops! Shouldn't happen, not even with a sketch. How embarrassing! Thanks!

Comment: @bmath completed the code up to the state: "works for me".

Comment: This is not complete. If the destination path is on a different filesystem, `mv` ends up copying the file, essentially doing what `cp` does.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik of course it's not complete, it is a sketch to give the OP a head start, not more and, hopefully, not less. The original implementation in e.g.: coreutils-8.24 hase 375 loc in `coreutils-8.24/src/mv.c` alone. OP's question has been answered at the beginning (the problem lies within the details of `rename()`), the rest is just an example.

Answer (score 2):

Like you know, mv is implemented by rename. rename is a atomic system call that can rename a file to a file , an emtpy directory to an empty directory or a directory to a directory(the dest must be nonentity). So there are following situation to deal with:

1. mv file1 file2 - use rename function
2. mv dir1 dir2(nonentity or empty) - use rename function
3. mv dir1 dir2(not empty) - rename dir1 to dir2/dir1
4. mv file dir(exist) - rename file to dir/file
5. mv dir file - illegal operation

can you understand?